# Как определить текущее время в int

Tags: java, android, datetime

Имеется несколько кнопок. На каждой кнопке должен быть текст в формате HH:mm, где HH - количество часов в данный момент времени + некоторое количество часов(конкретное количество зависит от определенной кнопки). Аналогично с минутами. Как вытащить текущее время в формате int и сделать так, чтобы время постоянно обновлялось?

Пример батона:

```
Button timeToWakeUp0;
timeToWakeUp0 = v.findViewById(R.id.sleeptime0);
```

я пыталась сделать самостоятельно несколькими способами, но приложение либо при запуске показывало время запуска и больше не обновлялось, либо в принципе вылетало вот пример кода, который у меня остался, где на кнопке показывало время запуска и больше не обновлялось

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); final String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); timeToWakeUp0 = v.findViewById(R.id.sleeptime0); timeToWakeUp0.setText(date);
```

Comment: Читайте про `Timer` и `TimerTask`.

Comment: вы что то пытались сделать самостоятельно, кроме примера малополезного в решении проблемы батона? что именно не получается? приведите пример кода, с которым у вас появились проблемы и опишите в чем они заключаются. Дело в том, что здесь не выполняют задания без попыток самостоятельного решения

Comment: Да, здравствуйте, я пыталась сделать самостоятельно несколькими способами, но приложение либо при запуске показывало время запуска и больше не обновлялось, либо в принципе вылетало
вот пример кода, который у меня остался, где на кнопке показывало время запуска и больше не обновлялось
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        final String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        timeToWakeUp0 = v.findViewById(R.id.sleeptime0);
        timeToWakeUp0.setText(date);

Comment: Этот код нужно добавить в вопрос с пометкой UPD

Comment: Также, по одному туториалу из ютуба:
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String currentTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
timeToWakeUp0 = v.findViewById(R.id.sleeptime0);
timeToWakeUp0.setText(currentTime);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял то вам самое лучше воспользоваться [SimpleDateFormat](http://www.seostella.com/ru/article/2012/02/05/formatirovanie-daty-v-java.html)
Или [JodaTime](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
Советую изучать второй вариант, он по новее и функциональнее, его рекомендует Google.

Так мы выводим теперешнее время:

```
DateTime.now().toLocalDate().toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm"))
```

Так будет выглядеть добавление одного час и 10 минут:

```
DateTime.now().plusHours(1).plusMinutes(10).toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE dd MMMM, YYYY"))
```

Эта библиотека предлагает достаточно гибкую реализацию ваших задач. Форматирование происходит [так](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) Принципы примерно такие же как и в первой ссылке.